# HTML2PDF Image tag not working

Tags: php, html, fpdf

I have following HTML code being displayed in pdf but image tag not working

```
$html.= "<h2>Header</h2>\n";
$html.= "<p>Text</p>\n";
$html.= "<img src=" . $path1 .">\n";

 $pdf=new PDF_HTML();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $pdf->Output('F',$filename);
```

Comment: What exactly does `$path1` contain? If it is just a relative URL, then I doubt HTML2PDF will be able to resolve that on it’s own. Try an absolute URL.

Comment: @CBroe path is `http://exampl.com/wp-content/uploads/borrowers/2.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use pdf->image for image to display. For Ex:-

```
$pdf->Image('logo.png',10,10,-300);
```

For referency, You can study [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm)

Comment: you are using src in html and then writehtml. have you tried in image also??

Comment: have you check $path1. Are you getting image in this?

Comment: try to use in jpg format. SOmetimes png image don't work if you are using png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164331/discussion-between-muhammad-muazzam-and-rupal).